# Node.js: Passenger puts stop to application because it takes too much time

Tags: node.js, cpanel, passenger

I installed nodejs on my website via the cpanel Application "Setup Node.Js App" and created the startup-file "app.js".

When I execute this file in the terminal with *node app.js* it works quite well.

Anyway if I access the page in the browser with the URL I get the error *"Website not available" (ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED)*. Sometimes though I get to a different window which says:

> The Phusion Passenger application server tried to start the web
>   application, but this took too much time, so Passenger put a stop to
>   that. The stdout/stderr output of the subprocess so far is:
>
> Item: apple
>   Item: eggs
>   Item: bread
>   Item: milk

When I click on the details it shows me this
[errormessage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1aHm.png)
.

The current code is

```
const readline = require('readline');
const fs = require('fs');

const myInterface = readline.createInterface({
  input: fs.createReadStream("shoppingList.txt")
});

function printData(data) {
  console.log(`Item: ${data}`);
}

myInterface.on("line", printData);
```

but so far, this happens with any code in app.js. Also when I only write:

```
console.log("test");
```

I don't know how to get the app working when accessing it by the URL.

Can someone please help me with this problem?

Comment: I think you need to set a web app using the [HTTP module](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-web-server-in-node-js-with-the-http-module) or [Express Framework](https://expressjs.com/)